# Nested Cursor not looping through all items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
    DECLARE @Webusers table 
(
    webusersid varchar(08),
    namefml varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Webusers (webusersid, namefml)
SELECT MAX(wb.webusersid), c.namefml
from webusers wb 
inner join contact c on c.contactid=wb.contactid
where c.contactrecordtype='CONTACT'
group by c.namefml
order by c.namefml


-- Store duplicate contact Webusersid that is not in WebUsers table
DECLARE @TempWebusers table 
(
    webusersid varchar (08),
    namefml varchar (100)
)

INSERT INTO @TempWebusers (webusersid, namefml)
Select wb.webusersid, c.namefml 
from webusers wb
inner join contact c on c.contactid=wb.contactid
WHERE 
c.contactrecordtype='CONTACT'
 and wb.webusersid NOT IN (Select webusersid from @Webusers);

 --SELECT * from @TempWebusers

--- create cursor 

Declare @currentWebusersid varchar(08)
Declare @currentnamefml varchar(100)

--Declare @innerWebusersid varchar(08)
Declare @innerorderid varchar(100)

Declare cursor_webusers cursor for 
Select webusersid, namefml from @TempWebusers

Open cursor_webusers
fetch NEXT from cursor_webusers into @currentWebUsersid, @currentnamefml 


/*select orderid
        from dealorder do
        where orderid<>'' 
        and webusersid<>''
        and webusersid IN (select webusersid from @TempWebusers) */


While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   -- declare all the dealid and webusersid that will need to be modified 
    DECLARE Cur2 CURSOR FOR 
        select orderid
        from dealorder do
        where orderid<>'' 
        and webusersid<>''
        and webusersid IN (select webusersid from @TempWebusers)
    OPEN Cur2
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @innerorderid

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN 
        --- update dealorder webusersid to the MAX   
        PRINT 'UPDATING '+ @currentnamefml+' '+@currentWebusersid + ' in '+@innerorderid

        UPDATE do
        SET webusersid= wb.webusersid
         from dealorder do, @Webusers wb  
        where wb.webusersid=@currentWebusersid
        and orderid=@innerorderid 
        and wb.namefml LIKE @currentnamefml

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @innerorderid

    fetch NEXT from cursor_webusers into @currentWebUsersid, @currentnamefml 
    END
    CLOSE Cur2
    DEALLOCATE Cur2 
END 

    /*DELETE webusers 
    FROM webusers wb 
    where webusersid IN (Select webusersid from @TempWebusers) */
```

This seems to be iterating only through the first 10 order ids and not looping through all iterations. Have done this nested cursor incorrectly? Something is off, not quiet sure. Due to this, the delete statement does not work as there are webusersid that are still associated in the webusers table. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You `END` is in wrong place. Also fix deallocation of nested cursor.

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @innerorderid

fetch NEXT from cursor_webusers into @currentWebUsersid, @currentnamefml 
END
CLOSE Cur2
DEALLOCATE Cur2
```

must be

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @innerorderid
END
CLOSE Cur2
DEALLOCATE Cur2 

fetch NEXT from cursor_webusers into @currentWebUsersid, @currentnamefml
```

Comment: That still does not seem to be updating all of them.

Comment: Seems? That not serious.

Comment: I meant it isn't, because when I do a select call the old webuserids are still there. Perhaps is there something wrong with the update statement? It should say 1 row affected or etc but instead it says 0 rows affected.